# Does Python have an importable audio clip dataset?

Tags: python, audio

I'm interested in manipulating and analyzing sound clips in Python, however I'm not physically able to download any .wav files to the machine I'm working from.

Are there any Python libraries that I could just import and use? Perhaps inside of some large machine learning library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for instance [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) has an example built in:

```
import librosa

audio = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
y, sr = librosa.load(audio)
```

The `audio` can be interpreted (and written) as a WAVE file.